# How can i group a duplicate row but add the non duplicate values of it in a list using R?

Tags: r, merge, row

I currently have a df called "phones" that is organized like this:

| ID | Phone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 55556666 |
| 1 | 33334444 |
| 2 | 11112222 |

and i need it to be something like this:

| ID | Phone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 55556666,33334444 |
| 2 | 11112222 |

i tried doing something like

```
merged_phones  <-  phones%>%
                   group_by(id(-telefones)) %>%
           summarise(amount=sum(telefones))
```

But is not working very well, do you guys have any suggestion? it seems to be simple but i'm struggling to find a solution

Comment: Try `aggregate(Phone ~ ID, phones, c)`

Comment: or toString instead of sum